# Bootstrap multipile checkbox with same id unclickable

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have checkbox like this

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="checkbox clip-check check-primary">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="machine" name="type[]" id="type">
                            <label for="machine">
                                Mesin
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="checkbox clip-check check-primary">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="utility" name="type[]" id="type">
                            <label for="utility">
                                Utility
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="checkbox clip-check check-primary">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="others" name="type[]" id="type">
                            <label for="others">
                                Others
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

My problem is i cant even check or uncheck my input. Is there i get worng with these code??

NOTE : I'm using same id because i need used to valided on jquery. If i'm using different id the validate did not working at all.

Comment: Change the ID. ID cannot be duplicated in HTML. The for attribute should contain the input's id.

Comment: An ID can only be used once.

Comment: For all, did you didnt see my note?? Like i said if i chenge the ID. The validate jquery i used it will didnt work.

Comment: @Wolfzmus you'll stuck somewhere else

Comment: @KK i did. My jquery validate get buggy, i was using different ID, and when i try using my jquery validate is not working, but after i'm reseting my jquery validate now is working with different id. I don't know why but now is working with differen id. Thank a lot.

Comment: "NOTE : I'm using same id because i need used to valided on jquery. If i'm using different id the validate did not working at all." Um, what? As others have said, IDs **must** be unique. If you have additional code that uses your duplicate IDs, then your additional code is wrong too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the HTML in this manner:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="checkbox clip-check check-primary">
      <input type="checkbox" value="machine" name="type[]" id="machine">
      <label for="machine">
        Mesin
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="checkbox clip-check check-primary">
      <input type="checkbox" value="utility" name="type[]" id="utility">
      <label for="utility">
        Utility
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="checkbox clip-check check-primary">
      <input type="checkbox" value="others" name="type[]" id="others">
      <label for="others">
        Others
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Keep the same value of ID which is present in the `for` attribute of label

Comment: I was trying using different id, but kinda bug for me. I cant even used validate on that. Aftyer i reseting my code. Now is working, i dont why. tq for your code.